# Как решить задачу?

Tags: python-3.x

Вот в чём заключается задача:

1. В предложении слова отделяются друг от друга одним или большим числом
   пробелов. Расстоянием между двумя словами равной длины назовем количество
   позиций в этих словах, в которых их символы различаются. Например, расстояние
   между словами “казан” и “кабан” равно 1, а между словами “кабан” и “баран” равно
2. Найти в предложении пару слов заданной длины, расстояние между которыми
   максимально. Если слов с такой длиной меньше двух, напечатать “нет”.

Формат входных данных:

- Первая строка ­ предложение.
- Вторая строка ­ длина слова

Формат выходных данных:

- Одна строка ­ результат

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки реализации алгоритма :)

Comment: Какие трудности у вас возникли при решении этой задачи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю надо действовать так:

1. Разбить предложение на слова.
2. Из всех получившихся слов выбрать слова, равные заданной длине.
3. Если их меньше 2-х, вывести соответствующее сообщение.
4. Далее берем 1 слово и сравниваем его со каждым из найденных соответствующей длины.
   4.1. Сравниваем каждый символ, если есть расхождение, увеличиваем счетчик на 1.
   4.2. Сохраняем слова и расстояние между ними
5. Берем второе слово и сравниваем его уже только с 3 и далее.
6. Если расстояние больше того, которое у нас сохранено, заменяем слова и растояние

Answer (score 0):

Не силён в питоне, но могу предоставить алгоритм решения.

1. Для начала стоит разбить предложение на пары слов:
   Предложение "Баран Капкан Коза Осел Орел Мул" должно быть представлено как "баран капкан", "капкан коза", "коза осел", "осел орел", "орел мул".
2. Проверить каждую пару слов на одинаковое количество букв в каждом слове и вернуть ее (если таких пар нет, то сразу выводим "нет"):
   в данном случае подойдет только пара "коза осел" и "осел орел".
3. Проверить каждую выданную пару на количество пробелов между ними:
   пускай в данном случае в паре "коза осел" между словами 3 пробела, а в паре "осел орел" - 7 пробелов.
4. Вывести соответствующую пару.

Извините, сразу не заметил "заданной длины". К пункту второму: проверить, одинаковой ли длины и совпадает ли с требуемом длиной.

Comment: Думаю выражение "найти пару слов", значит найти два слова.

Comment: @MaximK не отрицаю, а где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: Пункт 1. Разбивать надо не на пары слов, а на слова

Comment: @MaximK Я правильно понял, что автор хочет найти пару слов с максимальным расстоянием между словами с одинаковой и заданной длиной?

Comment: пара слов - это два слова, но не обязательно стоящие рядом.

Comment: @MaximK а, понял. Да, действительно, не подумал об этом.

Answer (score 0):

пункты 1-3 по MaximK, а потом  [алгоритм Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0#.D0.90.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC_.D0.92.D0.B0.D0.B3.D0.BD.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0.C2.A0.E2.80.94_.D0.A4.D0.B8.D1.88.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B0).

Для питона вроде даже библиотечки есть
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re # импорт модуля регулярных выражений
length = 6 # задаем требуемую длину слов
text = "пробка пробки нет кабаны кубань" # задаем текст
regex = r"\b[a-zа-я]{"+str(length)+r"}\b" # регулярка для поиска слов
words = re.findall( regex, text, re.I ) # находим все слова
# находим все разницы между всеми словами
diff = [ [word1, word2, len( [ None for i in range( length ) if word1[i] != word2[i] ] )] for word1 in words for word2 in words if word1!=word2 ]
diffs = [i[2] for i in diff ] # только разницы без слов
result = diff[ diffs.index( max( diffs ) ) ] # слова с максимальной разницей (первое вхождение, для всех надо цикл)
print( result ) # ['пробка', 'кабаны', 6]
```